# CSS Left align div regarding a center align parent div

Tags: html, css

My issue is certainly very easy regarding that i am new in css.

I will show you first a picture of my issue :

[image]

I am tryin to put the grey  to the left of the content alignes with my other div. The issue is that my grey div is always centered.

```css
.row {
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center !important;
}

.payment-title-div {
  color: #fff;
  background: #1282a2;
  width: 70%;
}

.u-left {
  padding-top: 0.5em;
}

.return-div {
  padding-left: 15%;
}

.payment-div {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 50%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="payment-title-div">
    <h1 class="u-left size12">
      <svg class="lock-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-shield-lock" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="M5.338 1.59a61.44 61.44 0 0 0-2.837.856.481.481 0 0 0-.328.39c-.554 4.157.726 7.19 2.253 9.188a10.725 10.725 0 0 0 2.287 2.233c.346.244.652.42.893.533.12.057.218.095.293.118a.55.55 0 0 0 .101.025.615.615 0 0 0 .1-.025c.076-.023.174-.061.294-.118.24-.113.547-.29.893-.533a10.726 10.726 0 0 0 2.287-2.233c1.527-1.997 2.807-5.031 2.253-9.188a.48.48 0 0 0-.328-.39c-.651-.213-1.75-.56-2.837-.855C9.552 1.29 8.531 1.067 8 1.067c-.53 0-1.552.223-2.662.524zM5.072.56C6.157.265 7.31 0 8 0s1.843.265 2.928.56c1.11.3 2.229.655 2.887.87a1.54 1.54 0 0 1 1.044 1.262c.596 4.477-.787 7.795-2.465 9.99a11.775 11.775 0 0 1-2.517 2.453 7.159 7.159 0 0 1-1.048.625c-.28.132-.581.24-.829.24s-.548-.108-.829-.24a7.158 7.158 0 0 1-1.048-.625 11.777 11.777 0 0 1-2.517-2.453C1.928 10.487.545 7.169 1.141 2.692A1.54 1.54 0 0 1 2.185 1.43 62.456 62.456 0 0 1 5.072.56z"/>
                    <path d="M9.5 6.5a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1 1.415l.385 1.99a.5.5 0 0 1-.491.595h-.788a.5.5 0 0 1-.49-.595l.384-1.99a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 2-1.415z"/>
                  </svg> <strong>Paiement sécurisé</strong>
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="return-div">
    <a class="titre" href="books"><svg class="arrow-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-chevron-double-left" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8.354 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708L2.707 8l5.647 5.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z"/>
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M12.354 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708L6.707 8l5.647 5.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z"/>
              </svg>Retour à l'annonce</a>
  </div>
  <div class="payment-div">

  </div>
</div>
```

Any indication ?

BR

Comment: why do you wrap everything in a container and apply display felx to it? if you want the elements below each other, you should leave them as normal block level elements. Then, what do you expect to happen when you use `justify-content: center; align-items: center;`? that is exactly used to horizontally and vertically center items within a flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

Well I've copied your code and I didn't get the exact same from your picture, but I'd recommend this changes in your CSS code:

```
.row {
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: column; /* set the direction as column (one element above another) */
  align-items: flex-start; /* align at start (left) */
  
}

.payment-title-div {
  color: #fff;
  background: #1282a2;
  width: 100%; /* I've changed this to 100% */
}

.u-left {
  padding-top: 0.5em;
}

.return-div {
  /* padding-left: 15%; remove this padding */
}

.payment-div {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 50%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

You can also check this [Flexbox Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to understand better how to work with flex boxes, It's really awesome am I right?